# Handling left to right content within an MSM site in AEM?

Tags: aem

How would you manage right to left content in aem for Arabic languages using msm; E.g. Search box, the search icon will be on left for Arabic site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Language specific styling is usually handled applying specific css/js to the content. I have not done Arabic site specifically but have done Chinese or Japanese which are also right to left.

As practice, your site could provide the locale information and based on that locale CSS namespacing can be used to get the specific language styling